# network checking application flex

Tags: apache-flex, networking, flash-builder

I appreciate any help or guidance that I can get. Thank you for going through my problem.

I followed this tutorial
http://www.jamesward.com/2010/04/01/video-build-your-first-desktop-application-with-flash-builder/

I copied that exact code that he wrote. But the application he built is working but mine is not. :(

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>

            import air.net.URLMonitor;

    </fx:Script>

    <s:applicationComplete>

            var mon:URLMonitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"));
        mon.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, function(event:StatusEvent):void
        {
        check.selected = event.currentTarget.available;
        });
        mon.pollInterval = 500;
        mon.start();

    </s:applicationComplete>
    <s:CheckBox id="check" label="Online" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" />

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Any clue or idea that you can help me make this app work please ?

Thanks
Bilal Ahmad

Comment: Please describe the problem: what's going wrong? Does it compile? Does it throw runtime errors? ...

Comment: It does compile and displays the application as it should except that the checkbox should be checked already when it is compiled, because I'm connected to internet, and when I disconnect myself from internet it should uncheck the checkbox in the app.

Thanks

Comment: Does that code in the `s:applicationComplete` block get executed? I must say: I've never seen an event handler written like that, though I guess it might work.

Comment: Yes Sir it does... here is an example of s:actionComplete being used as well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268351/how-do-i-set-the-dataprovider-for-an-slist-component-to-be-an-xml-file

Thanks

Comment: OK, now the code in the STATUS event handler function: does that get executed?

Comment: I guess, its not working... STATUS event is creating problem.

Comment: var mon:URLMonitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"));

I did put a break point at this point and it gives a NULL value to mon.

Comment: refer this [link] (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/net/ServiceMonitor.html#pollInterval). Problem is pollInterval. try increasing pollInterval to say 1000 it will take some time to enable the check box or remove completely

Comment: Thank you. Yes problem was pollinterval... no idea why was it behaving like this.. but I did set it to  0 ... so it starts as soon as application starts, it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets solved by setting the polinterval to zero.

For assistance please see the link below

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/net/ServiceMonitor.html#pollInterval

Answer (score 5):

I think you should declare both `mon` and the `listener` function in the `<script>` part, and leave just the `addEventListener` and the call to `mon.start()` in the `applicationComplete` event. I think `mon` is only live during the execution of `<applicationComplete>`, and discarded after, so the function is not being called.